# Is there a way to make localhost available from the CLI environment in a docker (for mac) container?

Tags: macos, docker, nginx, port, docker-for-mac

I have two docker containers called php-cli and nginx. They are running on my mac. My docker-compose file looks very roughly like this:

```
version: "2.1"
services:
    php-cli:
        image: myproject/php-fpm
        container_name: myproject_php-cli
        user: www-data
        entrypoint: bash
        depends_on:
            - nginx
        networks:
            - default
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.13.5-alpine
        container_name: myproject_nginx
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - ./:/usr/src/app:cached
            - ./.docker/nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
            - ./.docker/nginx/fastcgi.conf:/etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf
        networks:
            - default
```

If I open a browser and visit `localhost`, I get a nice index of files. But when I log into the `php-cli` container, `curl --verbose "localhost"` I get the following:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: localhost/
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80 failed: Connection refused
*   Trying ::1...
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address
* Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

I found a blog post saying to use `host.docker.internal`, but while that works from within the container, it fails in my browser. Since I'm setting up a finicky application's settings file, I need to be able to point the app at a base address that will work from both the host (browser) and inside the container (curl). I cannot use two different addresses. I also cannot use the name of the nginx container, as this is again only available from within my php-cli container, and not from the browser.

**Is there a way for me to get access to `localhost` from within my php-cli container without specifying the name of my nginx container and without using host.docker.internal? If so, how do I do that?**

===

Update: I tried adding the following to docker-compose.yaml:
        extra_hosts:
            - "localhost:host.docker.internal"

... but I got this as a reward:

> ERROR: Cannot create container for service php-cli: invalid IP address
>   in add-host: "host.docker.internal"

Oh well -- it was worth a try.

Comment: Maybe just [add a static hosts entry](https://www.imore.com/how-edit-your-macs-hosts-file-and-why-you-would-want) on your Mac that maps `host.docker.internal` to `127.0.0.1`? Then you could use that hostname both inside the container and in your browser.

Comment: @larsks That's pretty smart. I'll leave the question open in case a solution that doesn't involve modifying the host comes in, but I'm guessing this is what I'll end up going with.

Comment: I guess you can make PHP FPM  listen on port 80 inside php-cli container without exposing that port and avoiding any overlap.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I put into my `docker-compose.yml` file's `nginx` definition area:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:1.13.5-alpine
    ...
    networks:
        mynetworkname:
              ipv4_address: "172.20.0.8"
```

... and then I modified the `php-cli` container definition like so:

```
php-cli:
    image: tcs/php-fpm:5.4-sudo
    ...
    extra_hosts:
        - "localhost:172.20.0.8"
```

... and now it works. Note that I had to separately define the network at the top of my file, rather than relying on `default`. So now the top of the `docker-compose.yml` file looks like:

```
networks:
    mynetworkname:
        ipam:
            config:
                - subnet: 172.20.0.0/24
```

So yeah, the relevant, google-able parts here are `ipv4_address` and `extra_hosts`.

**Did this involve creating significant fragility in the way my docker swarm is set up? Yes. Do I recommend it for most use cases? No.** But it worked for my specific scenario when other options failed. I hope it helps somebody.